# What exactly is exposed terminal issue

Tags: radio-transmission

I have read a lot of posts on the internet and most of them explain the exposed terminal issue in a scenario like this:

`A<---B   C---->D`

B is sending data to A, cause C is in the range of B, C can sense the channel is busy therefore UNNECESSARILY defer sending data to D. My question is that is there any RTS/CTS involved in the exposed terminal issue? and while B is sending data to A, from what I understand, B will broadcast the signal to each direction. So if C is sending data to D, won't B's signal collide with C's signal at C?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this link](https://er.yuvayana.org/hidden-terminal-and-exposed-terminal-problem-and-its-solution/) does a pretty good job explaining it.

The exposed terminal problem occurs when two nodes (in this case B & C) cause excessive delays in each other due to the inclusion of mechanisms (e.g. carrier-sense based collision avoidance, RTS/CTS schemes) to avoid the hidden node problem. This is a result of the trade-off made to improve performance in the hidden node situation.

As the link mentions, there are techniques (like directional antennae) that could help improve these delays *(however, I would contend that using directional antennae is actually more like isolating both systems, not really fixing this issue)*.

You might be tempted to look at this situation with B & C and conclude *"well, I know that they won't interfere, they should just send anyway!"* But you must also consider that most wireless systems use acknowledgements etc to verify that data was received, which could also be affected by this choice. For example, let's step through a scenario where B & C ignore the busy channel:

- B has a long packet to send to A, checks the air is clear and starts sending
- C has a short packet to send to D, checks the air, ignores that it is busy and starts sending anyway
- C finishes sending, D sends an ACK back to C immediately
- B is still sending its packet, so C never hears the ACK from D, as B interferes with it
- C decides to start sending again
- B finishes, A sends an ACK back to B
- C is still sending its packet (2nd time), so B never hears the ACK from A
- And this is the song that never ends....